# How to insert IDENTITY column when creating table by this method (creating IDENTITY in table level)?

Tags: sql, identity, sql-server-2012-datatools

How to insert IDENTITY column when creating table by this method (creating IDENTITY in table level)?

```
Create Table ProspectiveTenant
(
PTID int,
Name varchar (25),
Email varchar (25),
ApplicationFillDateTime Date,
MetSamanthaDateTime Date
Add (PTID) Identity (1,1)--this is not working
```

Comment: Next time you post a question, _post the error_. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725705/how-to-create-table-with-identity-column

Comment: You **cannot** add `IDENTITY` to an existing column - you have to define a column as `IDENTITY` at the time the table is created