# Invalid Column Name when Inserting Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a local installation of SQLExpress, and accessing it using SQL Server Management Studio.

I created a new database `BirdSite` in SSMS, with a single table `TMasterCountry`, with these columns:

```
Id (int)
CountryName (varchar(50))
```

where `Id` is the primary, auto-incrementing key.

When I use the `Script table as...` option in the object explorer, I am able to view the empty table with this bit of SQL:

```
USE [BirdSite]
GO

SELECT [Id]
      ,[CountryName]
  FROM [dbo].[TMasterCountry]
GO
```

without any issues.

However, using the same option to try inserting some data, brings up this SQL:

```
USE [BirdSite]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TMasterCountry]
           ([CountryName])
     VALUES
           (<CountryName, varchar(50),>)
GO
```

So I changed the line under `VALUES` to

```
(CountryName, 'test')
```

But when I try running the code, I get these errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Invalid column name 'CountryName'.
>
> Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? The column clearly does exist, as I can `SELECT` the data just fine.

Following some similar questions on SO, I have tried restarting SSMS and also tried refreshing the local Intellisense cache, but with no luck. I also tried surrounding `CountryName` in square brackets but with the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to:

```
USE [BirdSite]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TMasterCountry]
           ([CountryName])
     VALUES
           ('test')
GO
```

`<CountryName, varchar(50),>` refers to name of column and it's datatype.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax error; Should be

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TMasterCountry]
           ([CountryName])
     VALUES
           ('test')
```

Comment: Also, unless you have specified the ID column as Auto Increment (Identity) then this will also have to be provided for in your SQL.

Comment: See [how-to-create-table-with-identity-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725705/how-to-create-table-with-identity-column)

Comment: It's already an identity column, as stated in the question: "Where Id is the primary, auto-incrementing key."

Comment: Spot on. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the entire content between `<` and `>` with the value:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TMasterCountry]
       ([CountryName])
VALUES
       ('test')
```