# How to add Identity Column in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity-column

[image]

Here is my table and Id is unique constraint...Now I want to add Identity Column in ID .Can anyone help me how to do it with TSQL.
This is existing table.

Comment: Duplicate of [How To Create Table with Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725705/how-to-create-table-with-identity-column)

Comment: Alter table TBL_NAME alter column ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: If u want to add an identity to existing column, I think it is not possible. Either u create a fresh table with identity or add a new column with identity to the existing table

Comment: @BrienFoss it's not duplicate of that you have mentioned. I think He wants to alter the existing column as an IDENTITY column.

Comment: Drop `ID` Column and recreate with same name `ID`.. with `not null` constraint with `identity(1,1)` property

Comment: @ Yogesh Sharma If i had million columns..do i have to delete it and insert again? ISn't there any other way

Comment: @BrienFoss How is this duplicate question...see both question carefully they are different

Comment: @Awesome i am not advocating to delete all columns. Just drop the ID the columns and add same column like `alter table <name> add id int not null identity(1,1)` simple no logic.

Comment: @YogeshSharma got it..

Comment: @Kavin ok, you got me. Here is your duplicate: [Add an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: @BrienFoss haha got it. But you should have mentioned it first itself :)

Comment: @BrienFoss haha...question may be but answer aren't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have 1 Identity Column per Table. So if you don't have one already, Just alter the table and add the Column. Like this

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD IdCol INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rename your previous ID column to keep those values if you need them in your application

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.id', 'oldid', 'COLUMN';
```

Then add new ID column with Unique constraint as follows

```
Alter table TableName Add id int identity(1,1) unique not null
```